# Ajax Post not working, even with correct data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm attempting to make a very simple chat app where you sign in with a message, that message gets stored in the database, and then you pick a friend and the database will send back their message that's stored in the database. For some reason, the message doesn't store. I've check the form and it is submitting properly, so the issue has to be either my Ajax request or the php file. Here is the code:

Final Assignment

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#sent').on('submit', function(){
                var Username = $('#username').val();
                    var Password = $('#password').val();
                var Message = $('#message').val();
                alert(Message);
                $.ajax({  
                    type: 'POST',  
                        url: 'sent.php', 
                        data: { username: Username, password: Password, message: Message},
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                        success: function(response) {
                        alert(response);
                        }
                });
            });
        }); 
    </script>
```

And here is my php:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("sql1.njit.edu","uname","pass","uname");
```

//my db name is the same as my uname

```
mysqli_select_db($conn,"kfp3");
    echo("Hello");

if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$text = $_POST['message'];

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Assignment5 WHERE UserName = '$username' AND Password = '$password'");

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE Assignment5 SET Text='$text' WHERE UserName='$username' AND Password='$password'");
echo("Success");
    }
else{
    echo("Failure");
}
    mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Please give details of the debugging steps you've taken. Are the `Username` and `Password` values being set in the JS? Is the data in the AJAX request what you expect it to be? What's the response from the AJAX request? And errors in the log fro your PHP code?

Comment: **Warning** You are _wide open_ for SQL injection attacks. Use [prepared statements with placeholders](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that.

Comment: **Warning!** Never store passwords in plain text. You should hash the passwords using [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and only store the hash. Then you use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify a password against a hash.

Comment: This is my very first IT course and, I'm just trying to get it done in time for the due date.

Answer (score 1):

You have not sent the message in the ajax data :

```
 data: { 'username': Username, 'password': Password }
```

should be  data:

```
{ 'username': Username, 'password': Password, 'message': '--message here--' },
```

Comment: $username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$text = $_POST['message'];

Comment: Oh crap, I didn't notice that. Thanks! I'll update it when I get out of stats in an hour. Does the rest of my code look fine?

Comment: Nope... read about mysql injection and password hashing. Your code is very unsafe and storing passwords in plain text beats the logic of having password in the first place.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't fix anything. The form is submitting just fine, so it has to be something with my AJAX syntax or PHP syntax.